# How to use VIEW in WHERE clause (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, where-clause

I want to use data of view in WHERE clause. But getting an error:

```
create view post_with_answers AS
    SELECT DISTINCT postid 
    FROM (SELECT postid FROM `qa_posts` WHERE `type` = 'Q') AS q1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT parentid FROM `qa_posts` WHERE `type` = 'A') AS q2 ON q1.postid = q2.parentid

select count(*)
from qa_posts
where parentid not in post_with_answers
```

On the last row I am getting this error:
`SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'post_with_answers' at line 3`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you would use a table:

```
select count(*)
from qa_posts
where parentid not in (select pwa.postid from post_with_answers pwa);
```

I would caution you from using `not in` with a subquery.  No rows are returned if even one value from the subquery is `NULL`.  For this reason, I recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select count(*)
from qa_posts p
where not exists (select 1
                  from post_with_answers pwa
                  where p.parentid = pwa.postid
                 );
```

In addition, your view definition is a bit over complicated.  You don't need subqueries:

```
create view post_with_answers AS
    SELECT DISTINCT pq.postid 
    FROM qa_posts pq JOIN
         qa_posts pa
         ON pq.postid = pa.parentid
    WHERE pq.type = 'Q' AND pa.type = 'A';
```

Then, the `DISTINCT` just adds overhead, so `EXISTS` is better:

```
create view post_with_answers AS
    SELECT DISTINCT pq.postid 
    FROM qa_posts pq 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM qa_posts pa
                  WHERE pq.postid = pa.parentid AND
                        pa.type = 'A'
                 )
    WHERE pq.type = 'Q';
```